# pygame, stop background scrolling

Tags: background, python-2.7, scroll, pygame

I want to stop the screen background image from moving with the player but I can't figure out how to do it. Below is an example, as the player moves the background image moves with it. I just want the camera to move with the player and the background to be stationary. Can anyone help?

**EXAMPLE:**

[image]

**CODE:**

```
import pygame
from pygame import *

WIN_WIDTH = 800
WIN_HEIGHT = 640
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 0
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    pygame.display.set_caption("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()

    up = left = right = False
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(32, 32)
    platforms = []

    x = 0
    y = 0
    level = [
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P              PPPPP        PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                     PPPPPPPPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P      PPPP                 PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "PPPPP                       PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P           PPPPP           PPPP     PPPPPPP",
        "P                                       PPPP",
        "P                                       PPPP",
        "P                                       PPPP",
        "P                         PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "P                         PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPP           PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]

    total_level_width = len(level[0]) * 32
    total_level_height = len(level) * 32
    #print(total_level_width, total_level_height)
    background = pygame.image.load("Untitled.png")

    # build the level
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                p = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            if col == "E":
                e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                platforms.append(e)
                entities.add(e)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0

    camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
    entities.add(player)

    while 1:
        timer.tick(60)

        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT: raise SystemExit, "QUIT"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                raise SystemExit, "ESCAPE"

            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False


        # draw background
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))

        #draw entities
        for e in entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))

        # update player, update camera, and refresh
        player.update(up, left, right, platforms)
        camera.update(player)
        pygame.display.flip()

class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l + HALF_WIDTH, -t +HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling left
    l = max(-(camera.width - WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling right
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling bottom

    return Rect(l, t, w, h)

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color("#0000FF"))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(200, 1200, 32, 32)

    def update(self, up, left, right, platforms):
        print(self.yvel)
        if up:
            if self.onGround:
                self.yvel = 0
                self.yvel -= 10 # only jump if on the ground
        if left:
            self.xvel = -8
        if right:
            self.xvel = 8
        if not self.onGround:
            self.yvel += 0.3 # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            if self.yvel > 80: self.yvel = 80 # max falling speed
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0

        self.rect.left += self.xvel # increment in x direction
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms) # do x-axis collisions
        self.rect.top += self.yvel # increment in y direction
        self.onGround = False; # assuming we're in the air
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms) # do y-axis collisions

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if xvel > 0: self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xvel < 0: self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom

class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color("#FFFFFF"))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bush.png")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want the camera to move with the player and the background to be stationary.

It's the other way round: the background is already stationary. You want it to move with the camera.

So instead of

```
screen.blit(background, (0,0))
```

use

```
screen.blit(background, camera.apply((0,0)))
```

and change your camera class to this

```
class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        try:
            return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)
        except AttributeError:
            return map(sum, zip(target, self.state.topleft))

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)
```

to allow applying it to arbitary coordinates, not only `Sprite`s.

Comment: this doesn't work, it wont take 0,0 as an argument it can only take 1 argument since self already counts as one

Comment: This works to a point, now it doesn't crash, but it no longer updates the screen correctly and movement causes the screen to blur everywhere. I'm not at my main computer to make a .gif of it so hopefully this makes since.

Comment: Yes, it's because your background image is not large enough to fill the entire level. Either scale it to be large enough, or blit it multiple times to the screen, at (0, 0),(0, backgroundimageheight), (backgroundimagewidth, 0), (backgroundimagewidth, backgroundimageheigt) etc... You'll get the idea...

Comment: oh shit yeah i was using the wrong image! Thank you so much for the help I've been struggling forever on how to figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the background doesn't scroll. Since the camera already does, you just need to store the current offset, and blit with that, instead of `(0,0)`

note using [rect's properties (docs)](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). replace these:

```
l, t, _, _ = target_rect
_, _, w, h = camera
```

with

```
l, t = target_rect.topleft
w, h = camera.size
```

*Things like HALFWIDTH can use the properties to simplify the math.  `topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
    midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
    center, centerx, centery`* etc..

Comment: what would i use as the offset then? l and t? I'm confused what you want me to use as the offset?